# Editing Excel Macro VBA to have it fill in Column C and right, instead of Column A

Tags: excel, vba, edit

I am currently using the Macro below for excel to move data from one one sheet to another. It is set up to fill from Row 2 down, as long as the rows are empty. I not want to have it already contain data in Columns 2 & 3. I have tried a number of things and am not having a lot of luck. I am new to this and "fixing" someone else's macro.

```
Sub MergeSheets()

Sheets("New").Activate
LastRowNew = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1))
For i = 2 To LastRowNew
    OrderNumber = Cells(i, 3)
    Sheets("PRIOrders").Activate
    LastRowPRI = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1))
    For j = 2 To LastRowPRI
        If Cells(j, 3) = OrderNumber Then
            Exit For
        ElseIf j = LastRowPRI Then
            Sheets("New").Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("PRIOrders").Rows(LastRowPRI + 1)
            Sheets("PRIOrders").Rows(2).Copy
            Sheets("PRIOrders").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        End If
    Next
    Sheets("New").Activate
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub MergeSheets()

Dim shtNew As Worksheet, shtOrders As Worksheet
Dim rngOrder As Range, rngNewOrders As Range
Dim f As Range, lastRow As Long

    Set shtNew = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("New")

    Set rngNewOrders = shtNew.Range(shtNew.Range("C2"), _
                       shtNew.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))

    Set shtOrders = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PRIOrders")

    For Each rngOrder In rngNewOrders.Cells

        Set f = shtOrders.Columns(3).Find(Trim(rngOrder.Value), , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If f Is Nothing Then
            'find the last occupied row in Col B or C
            lastRow = Application.Max(shtOrders.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, _
                                      shtOrders.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row)

            rngOrder.EntireRow.Copy shtOrders.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1)

        End If

    Next rngOrder

End Sub
```